# How to dynamically href link to a different folder but the same page name?

Tags: javascript, php, html, html-select

```
<select onChange="window.location.href=this.value">
  <option value="*">Show all</option>
    <?php     
    $categories = get_categories();
    foreach ($categories as $category) {
        echo '<option data-filter=".'.$category->slug.'">'.$category->name.'</option>';
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

This allows me to get to the categorized pages within the same folder (e.g works/filename), but i want it to link to a different folder with the same filename (e.g awards/filename). My code already dynamically returns the category names, i just need to change the `onChange="window.location.href=this.value"`, but i dont know how to access a different folder but the same name

Comment: Could you show an example of what `echo '<option data-filter=".'.$category->slug.'">'.$category->name.'</option>';` prints?

Comment: It dynamically retrieves the categories from wordpress posts and adds them as options. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ra4F_4qZRV4&list=PLylMDDjFIp1B9-lO5QKBWgEPThCQBosWE&index=5

Comment: If I understood correctly, you'll want to use an absolute URL as the value of your `window.location.href`, e.g. `window.location.href="https://example.com/awards/filename"`. See https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_href.asp